# How to get content when receive 503 or 404 header

Tags: php, curl

Sometime the HTTP 404 comes from the header on the response - there can be response content (usually custom error 404 page) or page 503 in Google.com browser will show captcha letting user to write the letters.

[image: Google Error Page]
<sub>(source: [goohackle.com](http://goohackle.com/imgs/google_error.jpg))</sub>

If I visit a 404 page in browser it will just load the custom error 404 page's content.
But in PHP cURL not show anything same as browser.

Can I use cURL to get content when header return 404 or 503 page?

For example code I create page to show  503 error in www.example.com/show503.php

```
header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
header('Retry-After: 7200'); // in seconds
print "This message will show only browser";
```

when I curl to www.example.com/show503.php with this code

```
$ch = curl_init('www.example.com/show503.php');
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($ret);
```

It get NULL value cann't get the content "This message will show only browser".

Comment: can you provide your PHP code?

Comment: I already add example code that can't get content for 503

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, so you won't get anything anyway.

This should work:

```
$ch = curl_init('www.example.com/show503.php');
curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($ret);
```

Answer (score 3):

For simple text fetching you can use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need

```
curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES,array(404,503));
```

see

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php :)